# ASP.net Web API 2:How WebApiConfig.Register is being called without passing parameter in Global.asax.cs file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, static-methods

I am creating restful service using ASP.Net WEB API 2.0. While reviewing the code, below is the code of RouteConfig.cs class file:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

In Global.asax.cs file the RegisterRoutes method of RouteConfig class is being called as below:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

I am very curious to know :

1. How WebApiConfig.Register method is being called as we are not passing any parameter explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GlobalConfiguration.Configure` accepts `Action<HttpConfiguration>` as a parameter. This is in a way "reference to a fucntion". When you use `WebApiConfig.Register` without `()` it's not the call to a function but rather a delegate that is passed as a parameter. `WebApiConfig.Register` has a correct signature, i.e. accepts `HttpConfiguration` as a parameter, that's why you can just pass it on to `GlobalConfiguration.Configure`.

Later the framework will call the method that you have passed and supply the parameter.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, so basically delegate function is playing important role here.